# maven-ant-run plugin fails due to missing class

Tags: java, maven-3

earlier i was using the maven repository for downloading all artifacts and thus my project built successfully. However when i deleted my local repo and  made my artifactory as a mirror of the maven site ..i get this error on building with maven 3.0.4:

```
NFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
RROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.5:run (default) on project leida-runtime: Execution default of
oal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.5:run failed: Unable to load the mojo 'run' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:mav
-antrun-plugin:1.5'. A required class is missing: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException
RROR] -----------------------------------------------------
RROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.5
RROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
RROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.5/maven-antrun-
ugin-1.5.jar
RROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolat
n-1.1.jar
RROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
RROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
RROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/user/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-nodeps/1.8.1/ant-nodeps-1.8.1.jar
RROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
RROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

I've cheked the jar for maven-antrun-plugin and it has the Ant-run class .Also in another jar org.apache.ant1.8.1 jar this class *org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException* is also present still i get this error..I'm not able to get how to resolve this..Thanks.

Comment: You saying you've checked the org.apache.ant-jar version 1.8.1 but the output is using version 1.5. So it looks like you are mistaken the version of Ant and the maven-antrun-plugin. So you have to define the correct version of the maven-antrun-plugin (1.7). Furthermore can you post your pom file?

Comment: in my pom file i've mentioned:  <build> <plugins> <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.5</version> </plugin> </plugins> </build>   But this is for ant-run-plugin which i've checked in local repo its 1.5 only...i've even tried keeping versions 1.7.0 and  version 1.7.1 of ant-jar in my local repo..still same error..The thing that is confusing me is that how its working if i download from maven repo?

Comment: What does that mean? "if i download from maven repo?" Have you tried to delete you local repository and rebuild ?

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a problem similar to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg123222.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise: yes i deleted my local repo and tried that

Comment: @Raghuram; thanks..i think the problem is similar..but i don't want to  use maven repo instead my own artifactory

Answer (score 0):

Maybe The m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar file is Corrupted. You should remove the m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1 directory and retry.